# Calling a JavaScript code from code Behind

Tags: asp.net

How to call the below JavaScript function:

```
function mySubmit() {
    document.getElementById('frm').submit();
}
```

inside  asp.net code behind function:

```
<%
if(!isPostBack)
{
    ----I want to call the above JavaScript code here---      
}
%>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't - javascript is executed on the *client*.

What you can do is register the script on the postback - which would execute as soon as the page is loaded on the client.

To do this you would use [`ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx).